# Sending username from Java to iframe

Tags: javascript, java, iframe, cookies

I have a fullcalendar being accessed within an iframe from both a standalone Java application and a browser based web application. I was working on the web application first of all and set the username using a cookie in Javascript. This will not work however from the standalone Java application.

What would be the easiest way of passing the username from Java to the iframe?

I'm thinking it may be over complicated to set the cookies from the Java application.

Another option is to just add the username into the URL (e.g. "../fullcalendar/index.php?username=admin")

I have tested this by pasting the URL into the browser with the username included. Then entered the following code in index.php (actually a HTML file, but saved as .PHP)

```
<script>       
    console.log(document.getElementById("username").value);
</script>
```

Output is: undefined.

Is it possible to just concatenate the username onto the URL or does it need to be set somehow?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is HTML code? in field did u set id="username" ? because you trying to access in JavaScript.

Comment: I had it between Javascript <script> tags, but it was edited, will change it back. How would I get the username in HTML?

Comment: Thanks 4castle, that worked!

Comment: Please select my answer then. Have a great day! :)

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to put the username in the url (e.g. "../fullcalendar/index.php?username=admin") by either just changing the url directly, or by using

```
request.setAttribute("username", theUsername);
```

and then put a small bit of PHP code into the HTML file. For example:

```
<span id="username"><?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?></span>
```

If you then want to get the username from the JavaScript, use

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks again, I may set the cookie once i have the username within the iframe, Will test this method now.

Comment: I added the code for how to get the username from the JavaScript in case you were wondering how to do that for the cookie.

Comment: Even better, good man yourself!